latte-dock doesn't show up
I have a Lenovo E-550 with Arch linux 6.9.7-arch1-1. I have installed latte-dock:
yay -S latte-dock

No errors or anything unusual. Then run it from konsole: /> latte-dock but nothing happened. I have checked list of processes ps cax | grep latte-dock and latte-dock is running. Killing the process and running it again has no effect.
I have tried latte-dock --replace or deleting its configuration from ~/.config/latte/
